# Bootstrap 4 - Grid broken with laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, laravel, grid, bootstrap-4

I have upgraded my bootstrap 3 to 4, and I have a few problems in the grid display.
I'm with Laravel 5.4 and i use nmp and gulp. I'm pretty sure that css and js are include cause if remove the link i have js error or my style page change.
But i have a simple page with just col-md-4 and it does not display it correctly (the Laravel auth menu is also broken and other col but i think it's the same problem).

My code :

```html
    <div class="container">      
        @foreach ($products as $product)
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <div class="product">
                    <a href="{{ route('app.products.show', $product->slug) }}">
                        {{ $product->name }}
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>    
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

But it's doesn't work it render like :

Product 1

Product 2

Product 3

Product 4

Instead of

Product 1      Product 2        Product 3

Product 4

I try to use a row after the container and before the foreach and it's work now but it's false (i think) cause my products are display in multiple line.

Somebody know why? It works on Bootstrap 3

Comment: <a href="{{ route('app.products.show', $product->slug) }}">  this line may be has a issue

Comment: you can use url() method ....{{url('app.products.show')}}

Comment: @MirthfulNahid Thanks but it's not that. I remplace all the <a> by a simple text like "Test" and it's change nothing. It's just a link to the product page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can use is to make `chunk`, each of 3 and iterate it over a `row`.

```
<div class="container">

    @foreach ($products->chunk(3) as $chunk)
        <div class="row">
            @foreach ($chunk as $product)
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="product">
                        <a href="{{ route('app.products.show', $product->slug) }}">
                            {{ $product->name }}
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
    @endforeach

</div>
```

More about [`Laravel collection chunk`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-chunk)

Hope it's helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think bootstrap 4 requires you to add a `<div class="row">` as a parent of the columns because of the reworked column functionality (becayse they added flexible column sizes) Not sure though.

But if you say it works with a row parent, why don't you use that?

Comment: It's works on this page but i have another pages and use of col. Like on table where I use a col-sm-1 to define the width of the column with the delete/edit button. And it's doesn't work either. The table is in a <div class="row"> and i don't understand why. I look to the bootstrap 4 docs and it's souhl works.

Comment: You cannot use `col` classes on a table. That's because the table cells have a `display: table-cell` option. They don't behave the same as a normal div regarding the size. But sizing table cells wasn't your question.

Comment: I use it on the <td>.

Comment: That is what I meant. Anything in a table: rows, cells and the table itself, cannot be styled with `col` classes. And again. This isn't described in your issue. You want to make normal rows working and you can do that with adding the `.row` div as a parent.